# System.Text.Json 6.0.2 Serialize error - trying to load System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1

Tags: c#, system.text.json, .net-4.7.2

We are using C# .Net Framework 4.7.2,  JsonSerializer in System.Text.Json Version 6.0.2. Solution builds fine. We get a runtime error when Serializing:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I confirmed that System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe Assembly Version 6.0.0 isinstalled as part of the NuGet package.
And that App.config contains assembly redirect lines pointing to installed Version:

name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"

bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"

Appreciate any help on how to resolve this - why is System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1 needed at Runtime. Thanks!

Comment: I am dealing with this problem at this moment. To make things more interesting, I have a windows application and a VSTO add-in in the same directory and the windows app works fine, loading version 6 of System.Runtime.CompilerServices. Unsafe but the add-in crashes when using JsonSerializer trying to load version 4.

Comment: For me, the add-in wasn't loading the "addin.dll.config" (with assemblyBinding) because of the adxloader.manifest not being present in the add-in installation directory. Once the  "addin.dll.config" was loaded the problem disappeared. My problem along with mentioned manifest is specific for the AddInExpress but I would make sure that you have the correct config file in the program directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.1.1 with a new .Net 4.8 WinForms application.

After some hints elsewhere, I opened the NuGet package manger for the solution.

`Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Manage NuGet Packages for the Solution...`

From there I searched for and added this package to the project that used `JsonSerializer.Serialize()`.

`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`  (V6.0.0)

To be clear this was not a listed installed packaged in the NuGet manager previously.

The runtime exception error changed to:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException HResult=0x80070002 Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Source=System.Text.Json`

So I then searched for and added to the same project:
`System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` (V4.5.4)

Again this was not a listed installed package in the NuGet manager before this install.

So far everything continues to work. I did not have to add these packages to the project that defined the class being serialized. Just the one that did the serialization.

Answer (score 1):

I've a similar issue with a .Net Framework project and I see that when you add a NuGet package that uses `System.Text.Json`, Visual Studio adds the below assembly binding redirect to the app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I think this is the way Microsoft chooses to solve this issue.
Tested with VS2019 and VS2022.

[image]

Comment: I tried many other solutions but this one solved it for me; thank you